# Can't able to start CKAN Redis service using docker. It's always in queued

Tags: docker, redis, ckan

I have an application with 2 user roles, Admin and Customer, With 3 states, Open, In Progress & Closed.
When the Customer adds a question on the forum, the state is Open, and I want to notify Admin and Customer using Email.
Admin can change the state to In Progress or Closed and any state change should notify all the Admins and the Customer who has posted the question.

The application is on Docker, and Redis is being used for Emails.

Problem: I am facing an issue while sending an email to any user using CKAN from docker deployment. I changed the email credentials using the docker paster command. Also, uncomment the Redis URL in the .ini file. But can't able to send mail the Redis worker always in queue state.

```
RUN paster --plugin=ckan config-tool ${APP_DIR}/production.ini "ckan.site_url = ${CKAN_SITE_URL}"
RUN paster --plugin=ckan config-tool ${APP_DIR}/production.ini "ckan.activity_streams_email_notifications = ${CKAN_ACTIVITY_STREAMS_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION}"
RUN paster --plugin=ckan config-tool ${APP_DIR}/production.ini "smtp.server = ${CKAN_SMTP_SERVER}"
RUN paster --plugin=ckan config-tool ${APP_DIR}/production.ini "smtp.starttls = ${CKAN_SMTP_STARTTLS}"
RUN paster --plugin=ckan config-tool ${APP_DIR}/production.ini "smtp.user = ${CKAN_SMTP_USER}"
RUN paster --plugin=ckan config-tool ${APP_DIR}/production.ini "smtp.password = ${CKAN_SMTP_PASSWORD}"
RUN paster --plugin=ckan config-tool ${APP_DIR}/production.ini "smtp.mail_from = ${CKAN_SMTP_MAIL_FROM}"
RUN paster --plugin=ckan config-tool ${APP_DIR}/production.ini "CKAN_SMTP_SERVER = ${CKAN_SMTP_SERVER}"
```

Any reference and guide would be a great help for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note here:

1. It looks like you have set the activity_streams_email_notifications to True and smtp.mail_from, if not make sure they are set?
2. Did you correctly set site_url because CKAN will use it to generate links?
3. You need cron job to call send_email_notifications so in your Dockerfile add CMD for doing that.